# Помогите исправить ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import os
today = datetime.datetime.today()
datenow = (today.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))

if str(datenow) == str("08/03/23"):
    print("_________                                   ___________")
    print("_________Прочти сообщение в папке с журналом___________")
    M = open("------------Сообщение--------------.rtf", 'w', encoding='utf8')
    M.write("C 8 марта!"+"\n")
    M.write("С наилучшими пожеланиями!")   
    M.close()
    
MS = list()

if os.path.getsize("Электронный журнал.rtf") > 0:
    f_read = open("Электронный журнал.rtf", "r", encoding='utf8')
    last_line = list(f_read.readlines()[-1])
    Number = list()
    x = 0
    while last_line[x]!=str(""):
        Number.append(last_line[x])
        x = x+1
    Number.pop(0)
    Number.pop(0)
    Number.pop(-1)
    Number.pop(-1)
    Number.pop(-1)
    Number.pop(-1)
    Number.pop(-1)
    Number.pop(-1)
    N = ''.join(str(x) for x in Number)
    N = int(N) + 1
    MS.append(str(N))
else:
    N = 1
    MS.append(str(N))


MS.append(datenow)
###Выбор протокола###
print("Выберите протокол: \n 1 - УЗИ \n 2 - ЭФИ \n 3 - УЗИ+ЭФИ")
NP = input()

print("Введите Фамилию Имя Отчество")
fio = input()
MS.append(fio)
print("Введите год рождения пациента")
gr = input()
MS.append(gr)
if str(NP)==str('1') or str(NP)==('3'):   
    print("Ввод данных УЗИ---------------------")
    print("Введите ПЗО OD")
    pzood = input()
    MS.append(pzood)
    print("Введите глубину п/камеры OD")
    pkod = input()
    MS.append(pkod)
    print("Введите толщину хрусталика OD")
    lensod = input()
    MS.append(lensod)
    print("Введите описание ст.тела и сетчатки OD")
    print("1 - Незначительная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("2 - Умеренная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("3 - Грубая деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("4 - Астероидный гиалоз стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    tod = input()
    if str(tod) == "1":
        tod = ("Незначительная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tod) == "2":
        tod = ("Умеренная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tod) == "3":
        tod = ("Грубая деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tod) == "4":
        tod = ("Астероидный гиалоз стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("Введите ПЗО OS")
    pzoos = input()
    MS.append(pzoos)
    print("Введите глубину п/камеры OS")
    pkos = input()
    MS.append(pkos)
    print("Введите толщину хрусталика OS")
    lensos = input()
    MS.append(lensos)
    print("Введите описание ст.тела и сетчатки OS")
    print("1 - Незначительная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("2 - Умеренная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("3 - Грубая деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    print("4 - Астероидный гиалоз стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    tos = input()
    if str(tos) == "1":
        tos = ("Незначительная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tos) == "2":
        tos = ("Умеренная деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tos) == "3":
        tos = ("Грубая деструкция стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
    elif str(tos) == "4":
        tos = ("Астероидный гиалоз стекловидного тела, сетчатка прилежит")
elif str(NP)==str('2'):
        pzood = str("_")
        MS.append(pzood)
        pkod = str("_")
        MS.append(pkod)
        lensod = str("_")
        MS.append(lensod)
        pzoos = str("_")
        MS.append(pzoos)
        pkos = str("_")
        MS.append(pkos)
        lensos = str("_")
        MS.append(lensos)
if str(NP)==('2') or str(NP)==('3'):
    print("Ввод данных ЭФИ---------------------")
    print("Введите ПЭЧ (мкА) OD")
    f_od = input()
    MS.append(f_od)
    print("Введите электрическую лабильность OD")
    l_od = input()
    MS.append(l_od)
    print("Введите ПЭЧ (мкА) OS")
    f_os = input()
    MS.append(f_os)
    print("Введите электрическую лабильность OS")
    l_os = input()
    MS.append(l_os)
elif str(NP)==('1'):
        f_od = str("_")
        MS.append(f_od)
        l_od = str("_")
        MS.append(l_od)         
        f_os = str("_")
        MS.append(f_os)
        l_os = str("_")
        MS.append(l_os)
###Блок описания УЗИ###
if str(NP) == str('1') or str(NP) == str('3'):
    x = 30
    x2 = 0
    x3 = 0
    x4 = 0
    x5 = 0
    x6 = 0
    x7 = 0
    x8 = 0
    x9 = 0
    x10 = 0
    x11 = 0
    x12 = 0
    x13 = 0
    x14 = 0
    x15 = 0
    listd = []
    while x15 < len(tod):
        while x < len(tod) and str(tod[x]) != str(" "):
            x = x-1
        d = (tod[0:x])
        listd.append(d)
        x2 = x+30
        if x > len(tod):
            break
        while x2 < len(tod) and str(tod[x2]) != str(" "):
            x2 = x2-1
        d2 = (tod[x:x2])
        listd.append(d2)
        x3 = x2+30
        if x2 > len(tod):
            break
        while x3 < len(tod) and str(tod[x3]) != str(" "):
            x3 = x3-1
        d3 = (tod[x2:x3])
        listd.append(d3)
        x4 = x3+30
        if x3 > len(tod):
            break
        while x4 < len(tod) and str(tod[x4]) != str(" "):
            x4 = x4-1
        d4 = (tod[x3:x4])
        listd.append(d4)
        x5 = x4+30
        if x4 > len(tod):
            break
        while x5 < len(tod) and str(tod[x5]) != str(" "):
            x5 = x5-1
        d5 = (tod[x4:x5])
        listd.append(d5)
        x6 = x5+30
        if x5 > len(tod):
            break
        while x6 < len(tod) and str(tod[x6]) != str(" "):
            x6 = x6-1
        d6 = (tod[x5:x6])
        listd.append(d6)
        x7 = x6+30
        if x6 > len(tod):
            break
        while x7 < len(tod) and str(tod[x7]) != str(" "):
            x7 = x7-1
        d7 = (tod[x6:x7])
        listd.append(d7)
        x8 = x7+30
        if x7 > len(tod):
            break
        while x8 < len(tod) and str(tod[x8]) != str(" "):
            x8 = x8-1
        d8 = (tod[x7:x8])
        listd.append(d8)
        x9 = x8+30
        if x8 > len(tod):
            break
        while x9 < len(tod) and str(tod[x9]) != str(" "):
            x9 = x9-1
        d9 = (tod[x8:x9])
        listd.append(d9)
        x10 = x9+30
        if x9 > len(tod):
            break
        while x10 < len(tod) and str(tod[x10]) != str(" "):
            x10 = x10-1
        d10 = (tod[x9:x10])
        listd.append(d10)
        x11 = x10+30
        if x10 > len(tod):
            break
        while x11 < len(tod) and str(tod[x11]) != str(" "):
            x11 = x11-1
        d11 = (tod[x10:x11])
        listd.append(d11)
        x12 = x11+30
        if x11 > len(tod):
            break
        while x12 < len(tod) and str(tod[x12]) != str(" "):
            x12 = x12-1
        d12 = (tod[x11:x12])
        listd.append(d12)
        x13 = x12+30
        if x12 > len(tod):
            break
        while x13 < len(tod) and str(tod[x13]) != str(" "):
            x13 = x13-1
        d13 = (tod[x12:x13])
        listd.append(d13)
        x14 = x13+30
        if x13 > len(tod):
            break
        while x14 < len(tod) and str(tod[x14]) != str(" "):
            x14 = x14-1
        d14 = (tod[x13:x14])
        listd.append(d14)
        x15 = x14+30
        if x14 > len(tod):
            break
        while x15 < len(tod) and str(tod[x15]) != str(" "):
            x15 = x15-1
        d15 = (tod[x14:x15])
        listd.append(d15)
        x16 = x15+30
        if x15 > len(tod):
            break
    ###Установление разделителя###
    ListD = []
    for d in listd:
        L = len(d)
        x = 30 - L
        D = str(d) + (" ")*x + "|"
        ListD.append(D)
    MS.append(ListD)

    ###Вторая колонка описания###
    tod = tos
    x = 30
    x2 = 0
    x3 = 0
    x4 = 0
    x5 = 0
    x6 = 0
    x7 = 0
    x8 = 0
    x9 = 0
    x10 = 0
    x11 = 0
    x12 = 0
    x13 = 0
    x14 = 0
    x15 = 0
    lists = []
    while x15 < len(tod):
        while x < len(tod) and str(tod[x]) != str(" "):
            x = x-1
        s = (tod[0:x])
        lists.append(s)
        x2 = x+30
        if x > len(tod):
            break
        while x2 < len(tod) and str(tod[x2]) != str(" "):
            x2 = x2-1
        s2 = (tod[x:x2])
        lists.append(s2)
        x3 = x2+30
        if x2 > len(tod):
            break
        while x3 < len(tod) and str(tod[x3]) != str(" "):
            x3 = x3-1
        s3 = (tod[x2:x3])
        lists.append(s3)
        x4 = x3+30
        if x3 > len(tod):
            break
        while x4 < len(tod) and str(tod[x4]) != str(" "):
            x4 = x4-1
        s4 = (tod[x3:x4])
        lists.append(s4)
        x5 = x4+30
        if x4 > len(tod):
            break
        while x5 < len(tod) and str(tod[x5]) != str(" "):
            x5 = x5-1
        s5 = (tod[x4:x5])
        lists.append(s5)
        x6 = x5+30
        if x5 > len(tod):
            break
        while x6 < len(tod) and str(tod[x6]) != str(" "):
            x6 = x6-1
        s6 = (tod[x5:x6])
        lists.append(s6)
        x7 = x6+30
        if x6 > len(tod):
            break
        while x7 < len(tod) and str(tod[x7]) != str(" "):
            x7 = x7-1
        s7 = (tod[x6:x7])
        lists.append(s7)
        x8 = x7+30
        if x7 > len(tod):
            break
        while x8 < len(tod) and str(tod[x8]) != str(" "):
            x8 = x8-1
        s8 = (tod[x7:x8])
        lists.append(s8)
        x9 = x8+30
        if x8 > len(tod):
            break
        while x9 < len(tod) and str(tod[x9]) != str(" "):
            x9 = x9-1
        s9 = (tod[x8:x9])
        lists.append(s9)
        x10 = x9+30
        if x9 > len(tod):
            break
        while x10 < len(tod) and str(tod[x10]) != str(" "):
            x10 = x10-1
        s10 = (tod[x9:x10])
        lists.append(s10)
        x11 = x10+30
        if x10 > len(tod):
            break
        while x11 < len(tod) and str(tod[x11]) != str(" "):
            x11 = x11-1
        s11 = (tod[x10:x11])
        lists.append(s11)
        x12 = x11+30
        if x11 > len(tod):
            break
        while x12 < len(tod) and str(tod[x12]) != str(" "):
            x12 = x12-1
        s12 = (tod[x11:x12])
        lists.append(s12)
        x13 = x12+30
        if x12 > len(tod):
            break
        while x13 < len(tod) and str(tod[x13]) != str(" "):
            x13 = x13-1
        s13 = (tod[x12:x13])
        lists.append(s13)
        x14 = x13+30
        if x13 > len(tod):
            break
        while x14 < len(tod) and str(tod[x14]) != str(" "):
            x14 = x14-1
        s14 = (tod[x13:x14])
        lists.append(s14)
        x15 = x14+30
        if x14 > len(tod):
            break
        while x15 < len(tod) and str(tod[x15]) != str(" "):
            x15 = x15-1
        s15 = (tod[x14:x15])
        lists.append(s15)
        x16 = x15+30
        if x15 > len(tod):
            break
    ###Установление разделителя###
    ListS = lists
    MS.append(ListS)
elif str(NP) == str('2'):
        ListD = ('_')
        ListS = ('_')
        MS.append(ListD)
        MS.append(ListS)                              
###Запись в файл###
UZI = open("Текущее исследование.rtf", 'w', encoding='utf8')
if str(NP) == str('1') or str(NP) == str('3'):
    UZI.write("------------------------УЛЬТРАЗВУКОВОЕ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ----------------------------")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("№"+str(N))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("_______________________________________________________________________________")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(datenow))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(fio))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(gr)+" г.р.")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("                          OD                             OS")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("ПЗО:                     "+str(pzood)+"                         "+str(pzoos))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("П/камера:                 "+str(pkod)+"                         "+str(pkos))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("Lentis:                   "+str(lensod)+"                         "+str(lensos))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("Стекловидное тело |" + str(ListD[0]) + str(ListS[0]))
    UZI.write("\n")
    if len(ListD)>1 and len(ListS)>1:
        UZI.write("и сетчатка        |" + str(ListD[1]) + str(ListS[1]))
        UZI.write("\n")
    elif len(ListD)==1 and len(ListS)>1:
        UZI.write("и сетчатка        |" + " "*30 + str(ListS[1]))
        UZI.write("\n")
    elif len(ListD)>1 and len(ListS)==1:
        UZI.write("и сетчатка        |" + str(ListD[1]) + " "*30)
        UZI.write("\n")
    elif len(ListD)==1 and len(ListS)==1:
        UZI.write("и сетчатка        |" + " "*30 + " "*30)
        UZI.write("\n")
    x=2
    while (len(ListD) >= x or len(ListS) >= x):
        if len(ListD) > x and len(ListS) > x:
            UZI.write(" "*20 + str(ListD[x]) + str(ListS[x]))
            UZI.write("\n")
        elif len(ListD)<=x and len(ListS) > x:
            UZI.write(" "*20 + " "*30 + str(ListS[x]))
            UZI.write("\n")
        elif len(ListD) > x and len(ListS)<=x:
            UZI.write(" "*20 + str(ListD[x]) + " "*30)
            UZI.write("\n")
        elif len(ListD)<=x and len(ListS)<=x:
            UZI.write(" "*20 + " "*30 + " "*30)
            UZI.write("\n")
        x = x+1
    UZI.write("_______________________________________________________________________________")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("                                               Врач:")
    UZI.write("\n")
    if str(NP) == str('1'):
        UZI.close()
if str(NP) == str('2') or str(NP) == str('3'):
    UZI.write("--------------------ЭЛЕКТРОФИЗИОЛОГИЧЕСКОЕ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ------------------------")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("№"+str(N))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("_______________________________________________________________________________")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(datenow))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(fio))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("          "+str(gr)+" г.р.")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("                               OD                           OS")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("ПЭЧ (мкА):                     "+str(f_od)+"                       "+str(f_os))
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("Электрическая лабильность(Гц): "+str(l_od)+"                       "+str(l_os))
    UZI.write("\n")
    if 35 <= int(f_od) <= 80:
        z_od = str("ПЭЧ: Норма")
    elif 80 < int(f_od) <= 110:
        z_od = str("ПЭЧ: Незначительные изменения")
    elif 110 < int(f_od) <= 179:
        z_od = str("ПЭЧ: Умеренные изменения")
    elif 180 <= int(f_od) <= 250:
        z_od = str("ПЭЧ: Значительные изменения")
    elif int(f_od) > 250:
        z_od = str("ПЭЧ: Грубые изменения")
    else: z_od = str("Значение вне диапазона!")

    if 35 <= int(f_os) <= 80:
        z_os = str("ПЭЧ: Норма")
    elif 80 < int(f_os) <= 110:
        z_os = str("ПЭЧ: Незначительные изменения")
    elif 110 < int(f_os) <= 179:
        z_os = str("ПЭЧ: Умеренные изменения")
    elif 180 <= int(f_os) <= 250:
        z_os = str("ПЭЧ: Значительные изменения")
    elif int(f_os) > 250:
        z_os = str("ПЭЧ: Грубые изменения")
    else: z_os = str("Значение вне диапазона!")

    if 40 <= int(l_od) <= 55:
        z2_od = str("ЭЛ: Норма")
    elif 35 <= int(l_od) <= 39:
        z2_od = str("ЭЛ: Незначительные изменения")
    elif 30 <= int(l_od) <= 34:
        z2_od = str("ЭЛ: Умеренные изменения")
    elif 25 <= int(l_od) <= 29:
        z2_od = str("ЭЛ: Значительные изменения")
    elif int(l_od) < 25:
        z2_od = str("ЭЛ: Грубые изменения")
    else: z2_od = str("Значение вне диапазона!")

    if 40 <= int(l_os) <= 55:
        z2_os = str("ЭЛ: Норма")
    elif 35 <= int(l_os) <= 39:
        z2_os = str("ЭЛ: Незначительные изменения")
    elif 30 <= int(l_os) <= 34:
        z2_os = str("ЭЛ: Умеренные изменения")
    elif 25 <= int(l_os) <= 29:
        z2_os = str("ЭЛ: Значительные изменения")
    elif int(l_os) < 25:
        z2_os = str("ЭЛ: Грубые изменения")
    else: z2_os = str("Значение вне диапазона!")
    UZI.write("                 OD: "+z_od+","+z2_od)
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("                 OS: "+z_os+","+z2_os)
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("_______________________________________________________________________________")
    UZI.write("\n")
    UZI.write("                                               Врач:")
    UZI.close()


###запись в журнал###

J = open("Электронный журнал.rtf", 'a+', encoding='utf8')
J.write(str(MS))
J.write("\n")
J.close()
```

Код ошибки

````
Python 3.11.5 (v3.11.5:cce6ba91b3, Aug 24 2023, 10:50:31) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

========== RESTART: /Users/maria/Desktop/TestProg/Исследование Test.py =========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maria/Desktop/TestProg/Исследование Test.py", line 23, in <module>
    while last_line[x]!=str(""):
IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: Я новичок, попросили с windows перекинуть в macos

Comment: Далеко не идеальный код. Хорошо бы его переработать. Он содержит огромное количество повторений. После переработки он займет раз в пять меньше места.

Comment: пусть попросят "перекинуть" не новичка, а того, кто разбирается. И вообще непонятно, что тут перекидывать - ничего специфично виндовского нет. Значит, код изначально выдавал эту ошибку.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо

```
while last_line[x]!=str(""):
    Number.append(last_line[x])
    x = x+1
```

используйте

```
for x in last_line:
    Number.append(x)
```

потому что ваш цикл, которого условие всегда исполняется (каждой символ неравен пустой строке) и так его последняя команда (`x = x+1`) будет выполнятся, пока индекс не будет вне допустимого диапазона.